# Tag pages with regular editor

Tags: tags, editor, template-tags

So, I am creating a website, review products and attach dozens of tags to them dependent on what the product entails.

I have a custom review template for my products and based on what I tag the products as they will automatically show under the given tag-page.

Now, my plan is to use the tag-pages to create content and rank with it.

The problem is that the tag-editor is pretty limited in regards to its functionality, so I do not have much freedom in regards to design.

I would like to have some of the options I have with the editor for regular pages and posts, available for the editor that's set default for tag-pages.

For example, I would like to create blocks/sections for my tag-pages and give it a featured image.

Basically, I want to treat the archive pages as regular pages with the help of an editor that allows several functionalities.

Thanks for any help.

Best regards,
Pierre

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? It's not clear which features you're referring to or the reasoning behind it. Tags are a type of term, not posts, they're stored and handled very differently, and what you've asked is very broad and vaguely defined, clarification will be necessary, please use the edit link under your question to expand on your question with **specifics**

Comment: Done! Thank you for your answer

Comment: I suppose what you are looking for is a custom taxonomy which would work like tags. You can attach the custom taxonomy to the post type of your products. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: Yes, that is correct but i have those custom taxonomies already. Now i need to add content to each tag, but it is difficult because the tag-editor is pretty limited

Comment: You can use ACF plugin to do that: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/